# Realm, Passing RealmObjects Models dynamicaly possible?

Tags: android, realm

I have thousands of Strings and depending on the contents I want to add them to different `RealmObjects` Models, and I have about 10 Realm 
Models,

right now what I doing something like this:

```
if (string.contains("abc")) {
        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(new ABCModel(string));
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
    }

if (string.contains("xyz")) {
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(new XYZModel(string));
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}

// and so on
```

I was wondering how can pass this to  a single method to do the transaction where i would just pass the string and the model class name,

How can I achieve something like this:

```
private void copyToRealm(RealmModel model, String string){
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(new model(string));
    mRealm.commitTransaction();

}
```

and call it like

```
copyToRealm(ABCModel, string);
```

and I want to do the same when querying like

```
public RealmResults<?> queryChemistry(RealmModel model, String year) {
    return realm.where(model.class)
            .contains("Title", "string")
            .findAll();

}
```

and by models I mean the class which extends the `RealmObject`.

if you need any more info lemme know I will update the question, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't strictly a Realm question to be honest, I personally would just create an enum that knows how to create its corresponding thing and how to evaluate if the model belongs to it.

```
public enum Models {
    ABC {
        @Override
        public boolean evaluateIfModel(String input) {
            return input.contains("abc");
        }

        @Override
        public RealmModel createModel(String input) {
            return new ABCModel(input);
        }
    };

    public abstract boolean evaluateIfModel(String input);
    public abstract RealmModel createModel(String input);
}

for(Models model : Models.values()) {
    if(model.evaluateIfModel(input)) {
        final _model = model;
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(_model.createModel(input));
            }
        });
        break;
    }
}

public <T extends RealmModel> RealmResults<T> queryChemistry(T model, String year) {
    return realm.where(model.getClass())
            .contains("Title", "string")
            .findAll();
}
```